# Why doesn't oxygen dissolved in water float to the top?

Tags: fluid-statics, buoyancy, gas

Shouldn't oxygen form (macroscopic) bubbles and thus float to the top, thus escaping the water? Does the surface tension of water prevent this bubble from popping and releasing the oxygen into the air? Does dissolved oxygen not form bubbles?

Comment: If it forms bubbles it isn't dissolved. Does salt stay as a solid when dissolved? No it doesn't.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Henry's law][2] and [Dalton's law][1]. These explain how gases dissolve in liquids and what the partial pressure of a gas is in air.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton%27s_law
  [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law

Comment: @HansWurst nailed it.  If someone wants to copypaste from those sources, that would be a great answer.

Comment: @HansWurst Just a pointer going forward: if you write `[text](URL)`, you get much nicer hyperlinks.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for the hint. I thought I could insert links as in the answer field, apparently I was wrong.

Comment: @HansWurst You're welcome. I tend to use the syntax I recommended in both contexts.